# Facebook: How to contact owner of a business account or link a Facebook page to a new business

Tags: facebook, instagram

I have a Facebook page. Let us call it "Company A". Under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=profile_access, under "Business Account Access", "Company A" is listed with a Meta business account ID of 12345 (as an example). The page underneath it is the page I am an admin of.

I select "Remove from business account" and it says it has sent a notification but no one ever gets this notification. Not one admin on the team. None one user on the team.

Now, I also have an Instagram account for "Company A". The business ID is 54321. I select the option to connect a Facebook page. It says I have full control over the pages listed below and it then shows me my FB page from the opening paragraph. Strange. I click "Next" and I get the "Something Went Wrong" error.

I go to the business assets for my Instagram page. My Instagram page is listed but not my Facebook page. I hover over "Add Pages" and the popover says "This action is not yet available"

- So how do I go about linking my FB page to a business account I have control over?
- How do I find out who controls the original business account that has an ID of 12345?

I have tried support but they send me to messenger which is completely blank